MDPI BIBLIOGRAFY REPORT
I should want to have my bibliografy style in MDPI, with \documentclass{report}. I try in different way but any way is impossible. I want this style with commmand \printbibliography. in {report} the bibliography style mdpi no exist. How i could can it?

Welcome to TeX SE. Could you add a minimal working example showing what you tried?

I doubt there is a biblatex implementation of MDPI style. A quick google search found https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/452341/35864, which suggests that at least at some point there existed a fairly official-looking template that included a BibTeX style. I suggest you look into that.
